# Add collection of products to a category

Tags: magento-1.8, product, category

How can i programmatically add a collection of products to a specific category without having to assign each one of them manually ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548352/how-to-assign-categories-for-products-in-magento-programmatically)

```
$categoryId = 6; 
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)->load($categoryId);
//get the current products
$products = $category->getProductsPosition();
//now attach the other products.
$newProductIds = $collection->getAllIds();
foreach ($newProductIds as $id){
    $products[$id] = 1;//you can put any other position number instead of 1.
}
//attach all the products to the category
$category->setPostedProducts($products);
//save the category.
$category->save();
```

Comment: Thank you this seemed to work. I have another a question if you allow me : i want to filter by attribute sku, i want SKUs that starts with 9780 followed by either 0 or 1 until 6. I tried  : 'like' => '9780[0-6]%' but that it returns nothing. 
What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: can you post new question for that.. as far i understand you want something like that  `$filter_a = array('eq'=>'9780');
$filter_b = array('from'=>'9780','to'=>'9786');

addAttributeToFilter('sku',array( $filter_a, $filter_b));`

Comment: Not quite, i have sku like : 9782145351552 and i want to filter sku that starts with 9780 followed by 0 or 1 or 2 .. or 6, the rest doesn't matter, i want know how can i use wildcard in this one.

Comment: @rachid kindly post another with this requirement.